# Using model's class static method directly, without "USE" keyword

Tags: php, laravel, oop, namespaces, laravel-5.4

I have "UsersController" file:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\User;

class UsersController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $request) {
        User::create( $request->all() );
        return "user added";
    }

}
```

"store" method corresponds to "POST" request:

`Route::post('users', ['uses' => 'UsersController@store']);`

So now, if I send POST data to "users" page, it adds new user to "users" table in DB.

Ok, this works, but I have question about `use App\User;`

if remove this line and then try to use "create" method like this:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    App\User::create( $request->all() ); 
    ...
```

gives error: `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App\User' not found`

Question is: why can't use "User" class static method "create" directly like this:

`App\User::create( $request->all() )`

?

Comment: \App\User::create( $request->all());

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace your

```
App\User::create( $request->all() );
```

by

```
\App\User::create( $request->all() );
```

Comment: Thanks, works, now much more understand, so this means that `use` keyword always looks for root folder?

Comment: it's not about the root folder, `use` keyword uses the absolute namespace directory so to speak , for example , if `App` refer to `/root/directory/subdirectory/` so when you are using `App` this mean you are using classes directly from this folder -so to speak-